# Unit testing with external data file in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am new to python and am trying to run unit tests injected with data from an external file:

```
class TestIsEquivalent(unittest.TestCase):

    filename = os.getcwd() + '\\data\\test-data.txt'

    with open(filename) as f:
        testdata = f.readlines()

    for value in testdata:
        print(value)

        def test_0(self):
            result = isEquivalent(value, value, 0)
            self.assertEqual(result, True)
```

I am getting the following error on line isEquivalent() is called with in the test function:

```
NameError: name 'value' is not defined
```

This would seem to suggest a scoping issue but I cannot figure out how to pass the value in the for loop into the test method. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your complete test case should be wrapped inside a function. I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do with a function definition inside a for loop, but moving `def test_0(self)` to the top of your classing does the trick.

```
class TestIsEquivalent(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_0(self):

        filename = os.getcwd() + '\\data\\test-data.txt'

        with open(filename) as f:
            testdata = f.readlines()

        for value in testdata:
            print(value)

            result = isEquivalent(value, value, 0)
            self.assertEqual(result, True)
```

But if you want to create multiple test cases that all you the values inside of testdata, and you dont want to read the file multiple times, you can use the `setUpClass` function that is executed once at the start of all unittests inside a class. The result would look like this.

```
class TestIsEquivalent(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        filename = os.getcwd() + '\\data\\test-data.txt'

        with open(filename) as f:
            cls.testdata = f.readlines()

    def test_0(self):
        for value in self.testdata:
            print(value)

            result = isEquivalent(value, value, 0)
            self.assertEqual(result, True)
```

Comment: Yes the second example is exactly what I was trying to do thanks